# pyspark dataframe array of struct to columns

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I have a dataframe with :

```
"abc": array [
    "def": struct {
        "id": string,
        "value": string
    }
]
```

id can be "PHONE", "FAX" and "MAIL"
So, this is a sample :

| technical_id | column_to_explode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [["PHONE", "083665xxxx"], ["FAX", "0325xxxxxx"]] |
| 2 | [["MAIL", "abc@xxx.com"]] |
| 3 | null |

Is it possible to transform to :

| technical_id | column_to_explode | PHONE | FAX | MAIL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [["PHONE", "083665xxxx"], ["FAX", "0325xxxxxx"]] | 083665xxxx | 0325xxxxxx | null |
| 2 | [["MAIL", "abc@xxx.com"]] | null | null | abc@xxx.com |
| 3 | null | null | null | null |

I'm trying with explode but it duplicate rows and I would rather to avoid this.

Thanks.

Comment: so, the struct's first element is the expected column name and the second element it's value?

Comment: yes, transform the first element to column header and the second to value

Comment: have you tried `explode` and then `pivot`? like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73303688/8279585)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `pivot` after the `explode` to ensure unique ID columns. Here's an example.

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([([('phone', 'abc'), ('email', 'xyz')], 1), ([('fax', 'klm')], 2)]). \
    toDF(['arr_of_structs', 'id']). \
    selectExpr('*', 'inline(arr_of_structs)'). \
    groupBy('id'). \
    pivot('_1'). \
    agg(func.first('_2')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+-----+----+-----+
# |id |email|fax |phone|
# +---+-----+----+-----+
# |1  |xyz  |null|abc  |
# |2  |null |klm |null |
# +---+-----+----+-----+
```

---

The input dataframe looks like the following

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([([('phone', 'abc'), ('email', 'xyz')], 1), ([('fax', 'klm')], 2)]). \
    toDF(['arr_of_structs', 'id']). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----------------------------+---+
# |arr_of_structs              |id |
# +----------------------------+---+
# |[{phone, abc}, {email, xyz}]|1  |
# |[{fax, klm}]                |2  |
# +----------------------------+---+

# root
#  |-- arr_of_structs: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- id: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: thanks samkart, it's working ! I just replace groupBy('id') by groupBy(myDf.columns) in order to show all columns in output.